# Let user download a XML file

Tags: php, header

I have prepared an XML string in PHP and I would like to let the user download the string in an XML file.

Is it possible to offer the user the download (e.g. text.xml) without physically saving the  xml file to the server?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/xml');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="text.xml"');

echo $xml_contents;
```

Comment: Tried this and the text.xml file downloaded has 3 carriage return line feeds at the top of the file.  Is this just me?

Answer (score 12):

If you use some kind of output buffering as a part of your framework you must add exit() below the XML output, like that:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/xml');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="text.xml"');

echo $xml_contents;
exit();
```

Otherwise you'll get the whole buffered page, not only the XML output.

Answer (score 1):

When you create the XML file first using for example php´s SimpleXMLElement
you might want to clean up first to prevent that html code is in that downloaded xml file. Here is what i came up with:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement("<root/>");
$xml->addChild("foo", "bar");

ob_end_clean();
header_remove();

header("Content-type: text/xml");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="foobar.xml"');
echo $xml->asXML();
exit();
```

This is how the downloaded "foobar.xml" file looks then:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root><foo>bar</foo></root>
```

Tested with Chrome Version 65.0.3325.181, Firefox 59.0.1 and Microsoft Edge 41.16299.371.0

Comment: FYI - you have a type here. Content-Desposition should be Content-disposition (and "i" not an "e")