# How to download generated xml file by a php script

Tags: xml, download, opencart

I am using opencart with a module for generating xml feeds of products in real time, so I created option in account of each client to generate the xml file by accessing a link

My question is how can I add download button for the client to be prompted to download the file in computer not to be opened in a new window.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Let user download a XML file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4349202/let-user-download-a-xml-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For downloading, instead of opening in window, You are doing exactly the same thing, but on top of that You need to set headers before echoing the XML contents.

Check this [question and it's accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4349202/let-user-download-a-xml-file) to see what shall be done before echoing...