# generate and download xml file after input submit (php and mysql) - JPK

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I want to do a page with form: two inputs (start and end dates) and two types of report to generate. One type of report is generated using one file, the other type of report using the other. To generate one of these reports, you must complete both dates. After entering both dates, click the button who generates the XML file and automatically downloads it to the disk as XML file.

XML is generated by using PHP, which extracts data from the MySQL database.

Unfortunately, I have a problem with creating this form, which after entering two dates will generate and save me an XML file in which there will be those rows from the database that are included in the given period.

I would also like to be able to insert three dates into this XML file: the date from the first input, the date from the second input, and the creation date of the XML file. The place for these dates is stored in PHP as: filecreateddate, startdate and enddate.

My PHP file:

```
<?php

/** create XML file */ 
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "XXX", "XXX", "XXX");

/* check connection */
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {

    echo "Connect failed ".$mysqli->connect_error;

    exit();
}

$query = "SELECT id, firma, ulica, nr, data_wystawienia, data_sprzedazy FROM FA";

$booksArray = array();

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        array_push($booksArray, $row);
    }

    if(count($booksArray)){

        createXMLfile($booksArray);

    }

    /* free result set */
    $result->free();
}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();

function createXMLfile($booksArray){

    $filePath = 'jpk.xml';

    $dom     = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8'); 

    $root      = $dom->createElement('JPK');

    $naglowek = $dom->createElement('Naglowek');
    $root->appendChild($naglowek);

    $naglowek->appendChild( $dom->createElement('KodFormularza', 'JPK_FA') );
    $naglowek->appendChild( $dom->createElement('WariantFormularza', '1') );
    $naglowek->appendChild( $dom->createElement('CelZlozenia', '1') );
    $naglowek->appendChild( $dom->createElement('DataWytworzeniaJPK', filecreateddate) );
    $naglowek->appendChild( $dom->createElement('DataOd', startdate) );
    $naglowek->appendChild( $dom->createElement('DataDo', enddate) );

    for($i=0; $i<count($booksArray); $i++){ 


        $bookid                     =  $booksArray[$i]['id'];  

        $bookNazwaKontrahenta       =  $booksArray[$i]['firma']; 
        $bookAdresKontrahenta       =  $booksArray[$i]['ulica']; 
        $bookDowodSprzedazy         =  $booksArray[$i]['nr']; 
        $bookDataWystawienia        =  $booksArray[$i]['data_wystawienia']; 
        $bookDataSprzedazy          =  $booksArray[$i]['data_sprzedazy'];   


        $book = $dom->createElement('FA');

        $book->setAttribute('id', $bookid);
        $book->appendChild($NazwaKontrahenta     = $dom->createElement('firma', $bookNazwaKontrahenta));
        $book->appendChild($AdresKontrahenta     = $dom->createElement('ulica', $bookAdresKontrahenta)); 
        $book->appendChild($DowodSprzedazy       = $dom->createElement('nr', $bookDowodSprzedazy)); 
        $book->appendChild($DataWystawienia      = $dom->createElement('data_wystawienia', $bookDataWystawienia)); 
        $book->appendChild($DataSprzedazy        = $dom->createElement('data_sprzedazy', $bookDataSprzedazy));

        $root->appendChild($book);

    }

    $dom->appendChild($root); 

    $dom->save($filePath); 

}
?>
```

My form with button must look like this:
[click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdJD4.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply retrieve your date fields from `$_POST` or `$_GET` arrays then pass them as parameters in SQL and as node values in XML. The type of web form array depends on the HTML form `method` used which you do not post. Assuming the below form, consider following PHP:

**HTML**

```
<form action="/action_page.php" method="post">
  Start Date: <input type="text" name="start_date"><br>
  End Date: <input type="text" name="end_date"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
if (!empty($_POST["start_date"]) && !empty($_POST["end_date"]) ) {

   $start_date = $_POST["start_date"];
   $end_date = $_POST["end_date"];
   $file_created_date = date("Y-m-d");

   $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "XXX", "XXX", "XXX");
   $booksArray = array();

   // PREPARED STATEMENT
   $query = "SELECT id, firma, ulica, nr, data_wystawienia, data_sprzedazy 
             FROM FA
             WHERE mydate BETWEEN ? AND ?";

   // BIND PARAMS
   $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
   $stmt->bind_param('ss', $start_date, $end_date);

   // RUN QUERY
   if ($stmt->execute()) {
      $result = $stmt->get_result();
      while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         array_push($booksArray, $row);
      }

      if(count($booksArray)){
         createXMLfile($booksArray);
      } 

      $result->free();
   }

   $mysqli->close();    
}
```

Be sure to update function by prefixing variables with `$`:

```
...
$naglowek->appendChild( $dom->createElement('DataWytworzeniaJPK', $file_created_date) );
$naglowek->appendChild( $dom->createElement('DataOd', $start_date) );
$naglowek->appendChild( $dom->createElement('DataDo', $end_date) );
...
```

Be sure to update SQL above for actual date field (i.e., replace *mydate*):

```sql
SELECT id, firma, ulica, nr, data_wystawienia, data_sprzedazy 
FROM FA
WHERE mydate BETWEEN ? AND ?;
```

Comment: Thanks! Form works fine with dates from inputs (only I used "date" instead "text"), but $file_created_date, $start_date and $end_date in appendChild not works. Have you any idea?
Maybe you know how I can set $filePath to add $start_date and $end_date after a fixed phrase?

Comment: Please be specific as *it does not work* is not helpful. What happens instead? Any error in log files? Empty nodes in XML?

Comment: OK, right. Fortunately I repaired this. I forgot that I had to add this variables in function. It was empty nodes in XML. But maybe you know how I can set $filePath to add $start_date and $end_date after a fixed phrase? For example - at the moment my $filePath is generated as "jpk.xml". I want to have something like "jpk_startdate_enddate.xml", assuming that "startdate" is $start_date and "enddate" is $end_date. It is possible? Assume that the date format is "dMY", but it's not necessarily. My dream is that this XML file should not be generated on the server, but only on my computer.

Comment: After you build XML, send headers for user to download: [Let user download a XML file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4349202/1422451). For server download use `file_put_contents('file.xml', $dom->saveXML())` where you change *file.xml* to string that concatenates needed variables.